# Jquery Slider/Banner with combination of UI-Slider thumbnails

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

can anyone suggest me if I can combine Jquery banner and UI-Slider widget together to create something like the banner on this website ? - http://corporate.arcelormittal.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it better way with CSS3. You can do it also with UI-Slider. The answer is in the real time changing value.

jQuery **sample**

```
$(function(){
  var slider = $(".slider").slider();
  $(".event-listener1").click(function(){
    slider.slider("value", 0);
    /* Slide to first image */
  });
  $(".event-listener2").click(function(){
    slider.slider("value", 20);    
    /* Slide to second image */
  });
  $(".event-listener3").click(function(){
    slider.slider("value", 40);
    /* Slide to ... */
  });
  $(".event-listener4").click(function(){
    slider.slider("value", 60);    
  });
  $(".event-listener5").click(function(){
    slider.slider("value", 80);    
  });
  $(".event-listener6").click(function(){
    slider.slider("value", 100);    
  });
});
```

And **HTML preview**

```
<div>
  <div class="slider"></div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="event-listener1">
    Change value to 0
  </a><br />
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="event-listener2">
    Change value to 20
  </a><br />
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="event-listener3">
    Change value to 40
  </a><br />
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="event-listener4">
    Change value to 60
  </a><br />
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="event-listener5">
    Change value to 80
  </a><br />
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="event-listener6">
    Change value to 100
  </a>

</div>
```